# How to populate a multi page form if data has been entered or leave it empty if there is no current data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hi really hoping to get some help with a complex form issue. 
I am building a real estate site where the agents will be able to log into an admin page and upload new houses that are for sale in an HTML form. I have a multi 3 page form that has Listing Info, More Listing Details and a Photo upload page. I have created these 3 pages and a nice css tab navigation to switch between the 3 pages. My issue is I would like the agent to be able to go back and forth between the 3 pages and have the data stay in the form. However if this is a brand new "Listing" then the form would be completely blank. I have the forms set up to submit through php and enter data in a mysql DB and then send you to the next page in the form.

The only way I can come up with is to have if statements that check session variables to see if a "listing_id" variable has been set. If it has it creates a form and fills in the blanks with the data from that pending "listing_id" if not it just creates a blank form. Is there an easier way to do this??? I would like to stick with PHP and HTML however simple JS would be ok too. Thanks for any incite anyone can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa whoa whoa. Not sessions. No .. hell naw.

A very simple solution is to make it so the tabs are only *visual*. Don't throw away the HTML, just hide the container and show another. This way, when you go back, your data is still there.

Comment: Thank you!! That is very simple and wish i thought of that earlier. One thing though i know how to easily hide and show the tabs with CSS when clicking on the actual Tab, but what about when the user clicks Submit on the first page I would like it to automatically go to the second tab. Would it it be best to do this with PHP if (isset($_POST['submit'])) --> then echo out some CSS styles to show the next tab? Thanks again!!

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly _going to the second tab_ means hiding the first tab and showing the second tab. In this case you don't need a `POST`. You just need a JavaScript function that switches some classes around to show the second tab. The final tab should do the `POST` request.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated this in the OP but each Tab is associated with a separate Table, so there are three tabs, three tables, and three Submits. Although your answer still makes sense as I can have the final Submit button on the third and final Tab do all the actual work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would save a cookie on their end with the data they have most recently put in and only clear the cookie once they have completed the form.  Then you can use this data  to fill the form.

For example,

Imagine the form data from their last inputs were separated by colons ":"

```
$prevform=$_COOKIE["lastform"]
$data=explode($prevform,":")
```

All the form data would be separated and reusable by setting the value of each input from `$data[int]`